# How to represent a formal proof

Tags: proof-writing, automata

I know how I want to do the proof, but I don't know how to represent it. It's an automata proof, so all I need to do is show that it is regular. How could I represent a DFA as a copy? So I have the automaton $L_1$ let's say and I want to copy $L_1$ to $L'_1$ basically. So, it will be the same exact language, have the same states etc., but i need a copy of it for the final construction. I just want to show that it's a copy.

$L_1$ is defined as $L_1 = (Q_1, E, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$. Could I simply just state
$L'_1 = (Q_1, E, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$? I just don't know how to show on paper what I want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of typing I’m going to remove the subscript $1$, since it plays no role in this question.

If you actually need $L'$ to be a *distinct* copy of $L$ and want to be somewhat rigorous about it, you’ll have to do some extra writing. You have (after minor modification) $L = (Q,E,\delta,q_0,F)$; I’m assuming that $Q$ is the state set, $E$ the input alphabet, $\delta:Q \times E \to Q$ the transition function, $q$ the initial state, and $F$ the set of acceptor (final) states. First you need a disjoint copy, $Q'$, of $Q$. A standard trick for constructing such a $Q'$ is to let $Q' = Q \times \{Q\} = \{\langle q,Q \rangle:q \in Q\}$; this ensures that $Q$ and $Q'$ are disjoint while at the same time providing a natural bijection between them. $Q'$ will be the state set of $L'$, and from that it’s easy to specify the rest of $L'$.

Certainly $L'$ will have the same input alphabet $E$. For convenience let $q' = \langle q,Q \rangle \in Q'$ for each $q \in Q$. Clearly we want $q_0'$ to be the initial state of $L'$ and $F' = \{q':q \in F\}$ to be the set of acceptor states. The transition function $\delta':Q' \times E \to Q'$ is defined by setting $\delta'(q',e) = \left(\delta(q,e)\right)'$. With these definitions $L' = (Q',E,\delta',q_0',F')$ is easily seen to be a DFA isomorphic to but disjoint from $L$, i.e., a distinct copy of $L$.

For your purpose you may or may not actually need this level of rigor in constructing $L'$. You *would* need it if, for instance, you wanted to combine two copies of $L$ to make some larger DFA.

Comment: Yea that's what i want. I have to create a much bigger DFA, but hey are clones.

Answer (score 0):

You can either say that $L'_1$ is a copy of $L_1$, or write it out explicitly (though that's not needed).

This type of proofs are not called *formal* but rather *informal*. This doesn't mean that they have no rules. The language of informal proofs is not defined explicitly anywhere, and must be learned by example. A general rule is that you're allowed to use everyday language whenever it's unambiguous (or can be disambiguated from the context). Also watch out for words which have a specific technical meaning in math.